# Gstreamer linking decodebin2 to autovideosink

Tags: c, video, gstreamer, decoder

I'm trying to add some processing logic to a program that chugs away on a local video file, but I'm having some trouble understanding how to translate the following (successfull) gst-launch command into code (and supply it with a "pad-added" callback):

`gst-launch filesrc location=/path/to/my/video.avi ! decodebin2 ! autovideosink`

I've tried my hand at gstreamer's [basic-tutorial-3](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+3%3a+Dynamic+pipelines), using `decodebin2` in place of `audioconvert`:

```
data.source = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "source");
data.convert = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin2", "uridecoder");
data.sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "autodetect");
```

However, I am never able to link `data.convert` to `data.sink`, as it is outlined in the example; the `gst_element_link(data.convert, data.sink)` always fails.  I suspect there's some special treatment for `decodebin2`.  Some gstreamer users have metioned [using ghostpads and seperate bins](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Using-a-Bin-td2997320.html), which after a swift attempt, also yielded no success:

```
data.bin = gst_bin_new("processing-bin");
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(data.bin), data.decoder, data.sink, NULL);
gst_element_add_pad(data.bin, 
                    gst_ghost_pad_new("bin_sink",
                                      gst_element_get_static_pad(data.decoder,"sink")));
```

I'm a little confused as how to continue debugging.  Does anyone else have any pointers?

Here is a boiled down gist of the current code: ([gist](https://gist.github.com/3266690))

====

Update: My callback is now firing, I think it was because I had an incorrect filename for the filesrc location (whoops)

Now, after following the advice below, I am able to confirm that I'm getting audio and video caps types and check against them in the pad-added callback.  However, I'm now getting the following "not-linked" error after one frame of pad processing:

```
Debugging information: gstavidemux.c(5187): gst_avi_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:gstreamer-test/GstBin:processing-bin/GstDecodeBin2:uridecoder/GstAviDemux:avidemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue I was running into is that I was listening to the decoder for new pads, when I should've been getting the static pad from the video sink.  I've updated the gist with my callback function to illustrate the difference.

Basically, it boiled down to this change:

I changed

```
GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->decoder, "sink");
```

to the following

```
GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->sink, "sink");
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains both audio and video, your callback will be called for both audio and video pads. Hence in the callback you should check the caps of the pad and ensure you are trying to link only the video pad to the video sink

Comment: My callback is now firing, and I am able to check against the caps type of each new pad and process them accordingly.  However, it appears that the stream loses its sink after one frame of processing.  I've updated my question for further illustration.